# How to prevent delete liquid

Tags: java, class, methods

I dont know what should i change in my code to prevent `del` liquid from bootle, when i move it from one to another(when its full).

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        Bottle[] bottles = new Bottle[x];
        for (int y = 0; y < bottles.length; y++) {
            bottles[y] = new Bottle(50, 80);
        }
        System.out.println(bottles[3].getContent());
        System.out.println(bottles[2].getContent());
        bottles[2].move(31, bottles[5]);
        System.out.println(bottles[2].getContent());
        System.out.println(bottles[5].getContent());
    }
}

class Bottle {

    private double content;
    private double volume;

    Bottle(double content, double volume) {
        this.content = content;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    double getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    double getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    boolean add(double amount) {
        if (amount + this.content <= this.volume) {
            this.content = this.content + amount;
        } else {System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        return false;}
        return true;
    }

    boolean del(double amount) {
        if (amount <= this.content) {
            this.content = this.content - amount;
        } else {System.out.println("yyyyyyyyyyyyy");
        return false;}

        return true;
    }

    void move(double amount, Bottle number){
        if (this.del(amount)){
            number.add(amount);}
        else {
            System.out.println("zzzzzzzzzz");
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: if (content + amount > volume) { ... } seems like a start. You need to calculate available volume as content - volume and then only move that much.

Comment: I tried like this
`    `boolean del(double amount) {
        if (amount <= this.content) {
            this.content = this.content - amount;
        } else if (this.content + amount > this.volume){
            System.out.println("duasd");
        }
        else {System.out.println("asdasdo");
        return false;}

        return true;
    }`

Comment: But it didnt work